# Making this diamond pattern with java (forloop)

Tags: java

Hallo everyone i just got a challenge from college for making this pattern, but i'am stuck with this pattern.

[this diamond pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVuCc.png)

Comment: Where is the code you tried?  We can't possibly know what you are stuck on without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is out to the console then this code does that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String end = "";
        if (i<=5) 
        {
            String inEnd = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                inEnd+="*";
            }
            end+=inEnd;
        }else
        {
            String inEnd = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < i-5; j++) {
                inEnd+=" ";
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 10-i; j++) {
                inEnd+="*";
            }
            end+=inEnd;
        }
        System.out.println(end);    
    }
}
```

in p5.js

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 let end = "";
 if (i<=5)           
 {        
let inEnd = "";
            for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                inEnd+="*";
            }
            end+=inEnd;
        }else
        {
            let inEnd = "";
            for (let j = 0; j < i-5; j++) {
                inEnd+=" ";
            }
            for (let j = 0; j < 10-i; j++) {
                inEnd+="*";
            }
            end+=inEnd;
        }
  console.log(end);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sam Oakes, I have a feeling this should be a bit more flexible than just fixed print statements.  If you notice in the above mentioned pattern, you follow a very simple pattern for a diamond that is `n` tiles wide.  I won't write Java code, because it is for school, but think about the rules of this problem:

1. Start with an empty string, `n` letters wide.
2. Starting from the right, replace the next blank space with a `*` character until the row is all `*` characters, or once you have added one `n` times.
3. Starting from the right, replace the next `*` with an empty character until they are all empty again, or once you have replaced `*` `n` times.

Pseudocode/Python:

```
def n_diamond(n):
    ##top half
    for i in range(1,n):
        to_write = ""
        ##change position is where the characters change from ' ' to '*'
        change_position = n-i
        for b in range(0,change_position):
            to_write += " "
        for b in range(change_position,n):
            to_write += "*"
        print(to_write)
    ##bottom half
    for i in range(1,n):
        to_write = ""
        ##change position is where the characters change from '*' to ' '
        change_position = n-i
        for b in range(0,change_position):
            to_write += "*"
        for b in range(change_position,n):
            to_write += " "
        print(to_write)


n_diamond(10)
```